# Maths error in PHP - number truncated?

Tags: php, string, math, double, type-conversion

I have the number `2.50` stored in a variable called `$price` which I can pass to a function and it recognizes the value `2.50` however when I try and multiply it with `2` I get the answer `4`. I assumed PHP is truncating the original value and then I thought it might be interpreting it as a String as I am getting the value out of an XML document but the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) says that it will correctly recognize it as `2.50` if it were a String. If anyone could shed some light on this I'd really appreciate it.

**Edit:** Here's the code I am using-

```
$Price = new Prices();

// Traverse XML document
foreach ($simpleXML->product as $product) {

    // Gather info from the product array
    $price = $product->price;
    $type = $product->type;
    $price = $Price->getRealPrice($price, $type);
}

function getRealPrice($price, $type) {
    // echo $price returns 2.50

    // Switch statement on type
    case 'Keychain':
        return 1.7 * $price; // This returns 3.4
        break;
}
```

The fact that 3.4 is being returned is the real problem, it's as if it is doing `2 * 1.7` even though it should be `2.5`; I chose `2.5 * 2` in my original example because it was more obvious to see the problem.

**Update:** 
After I do `1.8 * $price` if I echo `$price` with cast of `double` I get this: `2.503.6` The two dots kinda freak me out...

Comment: Can you show the code please?

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you tried to get the type of the variable `$price`. And as @ghbarratt said, Can you show th code please?

Comment: @ghbarratt I've edited my question to show the code

Comment: @SamJackson: you can do the following test: modify: `case 'Keychain': echo $price; return 1.7 * $price;` and tell us, what is a value of price the script echoes.

Comment: @SamJackson I still cannot recreate your issue.. Can you show us the output of a `var_dump($price)` right before the return?

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have somewhere in your code something like this `return 1.36 * $price;`?

Comment: @ghbarratt var_dump($price) returns object(SimpleXMLElement)[34]
  string '2.50' (length=4)

Comment: @Adnan No, I have other values under different cases but not 1.36

Comment: @Stano the script echoes 2.50

Comment: @SamJackson, this is unnecessary, but just for the sake of trying, do this  `return 1.7 * floatval($price);`

Comment: @Adnan Hey it worked! I echoed it after doing what you suggested and got 4.25! Thanks for everybody's help!

Comment: [Check this out](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php#100162)

Comment: I cannot seem to find a more official way of dealing with converting SimpleXMLElement to floats than casting (or using `floatval` as Adnan suggests). You would think that there would be a better answer than that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the string to a float by using [floatval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) this in the beginning of your function

```
function getRealPrice($price, $type) {
   $price = floatval($price);
```

Comment: A simple cast would also have worked. It is odd that casting actually seems to be the official solution to this problem. [Read this](http://php.net/manual/fr/ref.simplexml.php#78683)

Comment: @ghbarratt, well I wouldn't say it's a problem. I completely agree that casting/parsing should be left to the user, I wasn't aware that the returned value was an object, I thought it's a String (which would be treated as a float when doing arithmetic operations).

Comment: I wasn't saying `floatval` is wrong. I was mostly surprised there was not something in (or about) the SimpleXMLElement class that can be used to do this without requiring casting or `floatval`.

Comment: @ghbarratt, I know you weren't saying that, because it's correct :) so take it easy. Plus anything internal in the extension (SimpleXML) would be done using type casting, but the key point here is that what's returned is an object, it's up to YOU to parse it/cast it/burn it.. Actually I'd be pissed off if SimpleXML did that by itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a wild guess, but you should make sure the value is '2.50' instead of '2,50'.